# Django, updating DB column, rest_framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A bit stuck at updating column in DB. I am sending `put` request to update a column. But an error returns.

> assert isinstance(response, HttpResponseBase), ( AssertionError:
>   Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be
>   returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

here is the front end. sending `request`.

```
updateInvoceProject(id, company_name){
    return axios.put(API_HANDLER.database_api + "api/v1/update-project", {id, company_name})
},
```

**serializer.py**

```
class InvocesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Invoces
        fields = ("__all__")
```

**view**

```
@csrf_exempt 
@api_view(["PUT"])
def update(request):
    if request.method == "PUT":
        serializer = InvocesSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            invoce = Invoces.objects.get(id=serializer.data["id"])
            invoce.company_name = serializer.data["company_name"]
            invoce.save()

            return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #
    path("api/v1/update-project", invocesView.update, name="update-project"),
    #
]
```

But in the end, the error I mentioned above is popping. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You're not returning anything when the serializer isn't valid or method isn't put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are not returning anything when the serialized data is not valid.

you can simply make it like this, to make sure that it is going to return something in all cases.

```
@csrf_exempt 
@api_view(["PUT"])
def update(request):
    # if request.method == "PUT":
    # You don't have to check for method, since you already defined it
    # in api_view(...) decorator.
    serializer = InvocesSerializer(data=request.data)
    # Raises a ValidatinException which will be sent as a 400 response.
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    invoce = Invoces.objects.get(id=serializer.data["id"])
    invoce.company_name = serializer.data["company_name"]
    invoce.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

---

### Better Solution

I suggest that you use DRF's `UpdateAPIView` **(Do it the DRF way :D)**, in order to avoid getting into such errors, and also to avoid doing all the validation, and serialization by hand.

like the following:

**1. Keep your `InvocesSerializer`**, and create another one just for Updating `company_name`

```
# Inside serializers.py
class InvocesCompanyNameUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        return InvocesSerializer(instance).to_representation(instance)

    class Meta:
        model = Invoces
        fields = ('company_name',)
```

**2 . Create an `UpdateAPIView` class for that serializer**

```
# Inside views.py
class InvoiceUpdateCompanyNameAPIView(UpdateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['put'] # This is only to allow PUT method on this view.
    serializer_class = InvocesCompanyNameUpdateSerializer
    queryset = Invoces.objects.all()
```

**3 . Now append that view with a `re_path` to your urls.**

```
# Inside urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    #
    # you have to add "pk" url path variable, so DRF use it internally to identify
    # which object you want to update.
    re_path(r"api/v1/update-project/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/", 
        invocesView.InvoiceUpdateCompanyNameAPIView.as_view(), 
        name="update-project"),
    #
]
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I got your point about creating new serializer for the update. In the end see the problem as well. It's expecting all column names to serialize, but only getting `company_name`.  The thing is **DRF way**'s logic a bit off to me, why the hell I need to write a different class to update just one column? If I do that for each table I ve got. Then there will be bunch of codes... and using regex in the `re_path` to get `id`...  isn't it much more simpler doing it inside the view like in the question? Because at the first look, it's sure look complicated.